# Double Click on Your File(extension) & open it with your EXE(wpf application) gives prism module loading error

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, prism, mef

I have a WPF application (and I am using MEF container).I am trying to launch its exe on double click on my file type (for example: Test.abc). I have created the module catalog from xaml file using this code:

```
  var catalog = Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModuleCatalog.CreateFromXaml(
        new Uri("/MyNamespace;component/ModuleCatalog.xaml",
                UriKind.Relative));
```

and in ModuleCatalog.xaml I have given ModuleName, ModuleType and Ref. I have define Ref as:

```
Ref="file://xAAA.dll"
```

When I place my file type in a place where all the binaries (including prism binaries) are located then application easily gets launched at mouse double click on my file type.

But when I place my file type at some other location and try to launch my application on mouse double click then I get the following error:

Failed to load type for module xxxxxxxxxxxxx.

If this error occurred when using MEF in a Silverlight application, please ensure that the CopyLocal property of the reference to the MefExtensions assembly is set to true in the main application/shell and false in all other assemblies.

Error was: Could not load file or assembly 'AAA.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..

I think application is searching the required dll's in the location from where I am trying to invoke the application.

I am not sure how to solve this.
Any help would be great.

Comment: Add the relevant dlls to a directory in `PATH`?

Comment: @nakiya I am not getting what you have asked?

Comment: I have same error, please help